running headers with chapter
The following four files replicate the situation with respect to the two-volume work I have written.
Volume 1 (two files), namely. roottestVolume1.tex given by
\documentclass{amsbook}
\includeonly{datatestVolume1, datatestVolume2}
\begin{document}
\input{datatestVolume1}
\end{document}

and datatestVolume1.tex given by
\tableofcontents
\chapter[XXX] %terse running head
{\for{toc}{XXX} 
\except{toc}{XXX}} 
\label{Volume1Chapter1}
Some text in Volume 1 \ldots 

Volume 2 (two files), namely, roottestVolume2.tex given by
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\externaldocument[Book-]{roottestVolume1}[roottestVolume1.pdf] 
\includeonly{datatestVolume1, datatestVolume2}
\begin{document}
\input{datatestVolume2}
\end{document}

and datatestVolume2.tex given by
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Solutions to Exercises in Chapter~\ref{Book-Volume1Chapter1}} % the problem
\label{myLabel}
\lipsum 
See page~\pageref{myLabel}.

Generating PDFs roottestVolume1.pdf and roottestVolume2.pdf comes very close to what I have done with my book.  Unfortunately, for reasons I do not understand, links in roottestVolume2.pdf to roottestVolume1.pdf are not cyan.  Nor is the internal link in roottestVolume2.pds (page "3") red.  However, that is not the problem that presently concerns me, since it is not a problem somehow with the actual book.  Rather the problem that concerns me is the fact that the running header in roottestVolume2.pdf becomes "SOLUTIONS TO EXERCISES IN CHAPTER ??".  I understand well enough why this is so.  However, replacing
\chapter*{Solutions to Exercises in Chapter~\ref{Book-Volume1Chapter1}}

in datatestVolume2.tex by
\chapter*[Solutions to Exercises in Chapter 1] %goal=terse running head without hyperlink
\for{toc}{Solutions to Exercises in Chapter~\ref{Book-Volume1Chapter1}} 
\except{toc}{Solutions to Exercises in Chapter~\ref{Book-Volume1Chapter1}}
}

(which I thought promising)
generates garbage.  Apparently what works with \chapter does not work with \chapter*.

your documents do not load hyperref and so do not have links. And \chapter* doesn't update the header or write into the toc, so do not use them.

@UlrikeFischer AFAIR amsbook version of \chapter*{…} writes to toc and updates the header. But IMHO more important is your note about hyperref, which is absolutely correct: No links without link anchors.

Thanks to Ulrike andr cabohah for replies.   The files for my book do not invoke hyperref but do invoke prerex, which, given Ulrike's remark must in turn invoke hyperref.  As for the problem that most concerned me, I was able to achieve everything I desired by writing
